# How to create a real time notification system if I have a rails backend and clients which run on Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, real-time

One simple way to do this would be to have the client poll the server every 10 seconds or so, but I don't think that's the best way to go about it.

I don't want to broadcast notifications to all clients, but only to 1 client at a time.

The internet is loaded with articles on how to do this but I can't figure out which one is more appropriate for my problem.

https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails

https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub

Comment: Implementing a small Node.js SocketIO server would probably be the best solution... I like Sails.js

Comment: You can use channels in private_pub to send notifications to only that client who has subscribed to one channel. Same with websocket-rails

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a hosted pub/sub broker like [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) or [Realtime](http://framework.realtime.co/messaging/) (the company I work for) and focus on developing your app and not managing the required real-time infrastructure.

From your Rails backend you would send the messages through the REST API and use the websocket-based JavaScript library to receive them on browser clients (subscribe).

For private messages simply subscribe each user to their own private channel (maybe using their user id).